# How to get /usr/bin/mail to send mail via gmail on Mac 10.14?

Tags: macos, email, gmail, sendmail

I am attempting to get /usr/bin/mail to work from the command line on my Mac Server running OS X 10.12 in order to implement a php routine that will route an http request from an external CRM site to another site that provides text messaging via email.  I've investigated several sources and added my gmail credentials to /etc/postfix/smtp_sasl_passwords, smtp_tls_sites, worked with /etc/postfix/main.cf, reloaded postfix, etc.  I have tested that I can log into my gmail account using the credentials I stored in the smtp_sasl_passwords file and can send and receive mail from there.  I keep getting Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.

I've read the page that is then suggested, but it seems like I'm providing all of that information. I would appreciate suggestions on how to pin down what authentication is missing or erroneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that google, the email server I was using, has changed to use two-factor authentication and that required me to obtain a special 'password' to be used when communicating through postfix mail.  Once I obtained that and replaced my normal password with this special one, everything started to work.  Here is what worked in /etc/postfix/main.cf just after the #relayhost = $mydomain

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
# Separate recommendation from stackoverflow.com/questions/26447316/
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
```

AND, you have to provide a file 'sasl_passwd', containing

[smtp.gmail.com]:587 userid@gmail.com:special_password they provide

Then run:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postfix reload
```

This seemed to fix things for me.  Hope they help someone else.